# Identifying the nth inserted element of matrix which fills by inserting alternating upper and lower triangle elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, matrix

I am trying to write a function that is able to map the nth inserted element into a matrix to its (i,j) position. It is known that the method filling this matrix, is doing so in the following way non-standard way.

(0,0)...(0,1)...(1,0)...(0,2)...(2,0)...(n,0)...(0,n)...
(1,1)....(1,2)...(2,1)...(n,1)...(1,n)
.....(n,n)

In other words it starts at the top left, and then after inserting the diagonal element, it inserts alternating elements into the upper and lower triangle all the way across the outter row & column, then rinses and repeats as it steps one row / one column in.

And what I am trying to achieve is a function

```
std::pair<int,int> getMatrixCoordinates (int nthElement)
{

return std::pair<int,int> (row, col) ;


}
```

Comment: Unless `n` is a constant, you'd also need `n` to do the computation.

Comment: Yes n is a known constant and the matrix is nxn..Lets say for this example 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This merely takes a bit of programming:

```
template <int N>
std::pair<int, int> getMatrixCoordinates(int i)
{
    int a(N - std::sqrt(N * N - i));
    int b(i - (2 * N - a) * a);
    int c(a + (b + 1) / 2);
    return std::make_pair(b & 1? a: c, b & 1? c: a);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about your answer, but I don't understand the reason of that operations. Could you provide a explanation about the process? Thanks

Comment: @Manu343726: You mean, for a complete homework assignment you'd need an explanation, too, not just the code? Well, first the diagonal position is determined, next the offset from the beginning of that position is determined, then the cell index is determined, and finally the coordinates are put into the correct location. Oddly enough, I don't need homework assignments anymore.

Comment: I think you have got confused between OP and somebody commenting in the thread...